# Combining 2 Arrays when value is matched

Tags: php, html, arrays

So I have these arrays that is fetched from 2 different database, I would like to combine them in one array when the **['item_name']** and **['name']** is matched then getting the **['id']** from the *Array2*

I tried doing the in_array but since it's multi dimensional, I can't get the right output I want, I tried foreach also but I can't also get the right output or maybe I'm doing it wrong, I'm running out of idea how I could do the output I wanted.

Example Array1:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 1
            [item_name] => Bag
            [Color] => Purple
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 2
            [item_name] => Pencil
            [Color] => Yellow
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 3
            [item_name] => Tumbler
            [Color] => Blue
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 4
            [item_name] => Shirt
            [Color] => Red
        )

)
```

Example Array2:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11
            [name] => Bag
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 22
            [name] => Pencil
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 33
            [name] => Tumbler
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 44
            [name] => Shirt
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 55
            [name] => Paper
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 66
            [name] => Chair
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => Notebook
        )

)
```

So my expected output would be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11
            [name] => Bag
            [Color] => Purple
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 22
            [name] => Pencil
            [Color] => Yellow
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 33
            [name] => Tumbler
            [Color] => Blue
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 44
            [name] => Shirt
            [Color] => Red
        )
)
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes, I tried in_array, I also tried the recursive array I found but I still can't get it, currently I am using the array_intersect() but I can only use it to only get the name, not the other details like the id and the color.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried and what result it produces. We're glad to help you with your existing code, but we won't write it all for you. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: $filtered = array_intersect($array1, $array2);


function in_array_r($needle, $haystack, $strict = false) {
    foreach ($haystack as $item) {
        if (($strict ? $item === $needle : $item == $needle) || (is_array($item) && in_array_r($needle, $item, $strict))) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

$compare = array($filtered, $array1);
foreach($array2 as $val){
 if (in_array_r($val['name'], $compare)){
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($val['name']);
  echo "</pre>";
 }
}

Comment: Please update your question to include the code. Code in comments are pretty unreadable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a map with the names and the ID from the second array and then loop to modify the first one.

Consider the following code:

```
$a1 = array("item_id" => 1, "item_name" => "Bag", "Color" => "Purple");
$a2 = array("item_id" => 2, "item_name" => "Pencil", "Color" => "Yellow");
$a3 = array("item_id" => 3, "item_name" => "Tumbler", "Color" => "Blue");
$b1 = array("item_id" => 11, "item_name" => "Bag");
$b2 = array("item_id" => 22, "item_name" => "Pencil");
$b3 = array("item_id" => 33, "item_name" => "Tumbler");
$arr1 = array($a1, $a2, $a3);
$arr2 = array($b1, $b2, $b3);

$map = []; // here keys are names and value are the id 
foreach($arr2 as $elem)
    $map[$elem["item_name"]] = $elem["item_id"];


$ans = [];
foreach ($arr1 as $elem) {
    if (array_key_exists($elem["item_name"], $map))  {
        $elem["item_id"] = $map[$elem["item_name"]];
        $ans[] = $elem;
    }
}

echo print_r($ans);
```

In this way you achieve complexity of `O(n)` instead of `O(n^2)` if trying nested for-loop

Comment: I saw this a little bit late, been trying to simplify my code and made it work my code seems similar to yours.

Comment: @kairi - if you can improve my answer as you got better solution please do. If it fine and helped you please mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

Try by using foreach loop.
Check if in foreach loop if any index value match with another array then create a new array with all those values.
You can use counter here to get the value of array inside loop.

Comment: Instead of explaining what the code should look like, you should write a proper example. Otherwise, it's more of a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Been trying to simplify my code earlier and I think I got it, thanks to anju and  David Winder, if anyone interested how I did it, this is how:

```
index = 0;
foreach ($array1 as $val){
    foreach ($array2 as $val2){
        if ($val['item_id'] == $val2['id']){
            $filtered[$index]['id'] = $val2['id'];
            $filtered[$index]['name'] = $val2['name'];
            $filtered[$index]['color'] = $val['color'];
            $index++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just pointing out that this is O(n^2). Better solution is possible with O(n) - See my post.